# Avast crashes explorer.exe

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, avast

I have the latest Avast with 13 shields active on a home PC with Windows 11 .

After a while of use (opening some files from local disks etc.) the exporer.exe starts to show errors like "Access to file denied", "No app associated with file", becomes generally unstable with e.g. search unavailable and finally explorer.exe crashes `e0465043, exception 00007FFA54C1441C` and restarts.

When I turn off all Avast shields and restart explorer.exe, the explorer.exe works just fine and no errors or problems appear.

Is there any solution other than disabling Avast?

Comment: You may easily be as far ahead to completely remove Avast and rely on Windows Defender.  That works perfectly well and is a better match for Windows 11.

Comment: @John In fact it's my father's PC and older people tend to think that 13 shields is much better than just one :)

Comment: Does the version of Avast your using explicitly support Windows 11?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal, tell your father the crashes are a feature of Avast! so that people will occasionally shut thier PC and take a break. Of course, if he doesn't want that feature, use *free* Defender or an alternative: https://alternativeto.net/software/avast-home-edition/ . **N.B.** Completely uninstall Avast! before adding another antimalware suite: https://support.avast.com/en-ae/article/Uninstall-Antivirus/#pc